Nested sequence of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$
I consider a nested sequence of non empty open intervals of the form $(a_n,b_n)$ where $a_n<a_{n+1}$ and $b_n>b_{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
I want to prove that the intersection is non empty.
Here is my attempt :
Clearly the sequence $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge as they are monotonic and bounded. Moreover by definition, $a_n<b_n$ and $(b_n-a_n)$ converges to $0$.
By a well known theorem from calculus we have  $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=c=lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$.
From this we have
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, \exists m_n\in\mathbb{N} : (c-\frac{1}{m_n}, c+\frac{1}{m_n})\subset (a_n,b_n)
$$
Since $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})\subset (a_n,b_n)$ the sequence $m_n$ is increasing and goes to $\infty$. Thus we have
$$
\cap_{n\geq 1}(c-\frac{1}{m_n}, c+\frac{1}{m_n})\subset(a_n, b_n)
$$
But $\cap_{n\geq 1}(c-\frac{1}{m_n}, c+\frac{1}{m_n}) = c$ so the intersection of the $(a_n,b_n)$ is non empty.
I think that there is more efficient way to prove this result but what I had in mind is based on this kind of technique. So I would like to know if it seems correct please, and if not, any hints is welcome !
Thank you a lot !

As notice in the comments the claim that $(b_n-a_n)\to 0$ is not royal in general, we need to distinguish two cases

$(b_n-a_n)\to 0$ has been treated

$(b_n-a_n)$ do not converges to $0$. We must have $lim_{n}b_n=b>a=lim_{n}a_n$ We infer that $(a,b)\subset (a_n,b_n)$ for all $n$ hence the conclusion



Why do you claim that, by definition $\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n-a_n)=0$?

Let $(a_n,b_n)$ be $(1-\frac{1}{n}),2+\frac{1}{n})$. Here $lim_{n \to \infty} (b_n - a_n) = 1$.

My bad. You are right ! Thank you !

$a_n \uparrow a, b_n \downarrow b$ and so $ a \le b$. In particular, any $c \in [a,b]$ lies in all intervals.

Your proof is generally good. Here are some suggestions to improve it.

Don't distinguish between the two cases. Just observe that $a_n < b_n$ for each $n$ implies $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \leq \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$, so you can pick $c$ such that $\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \leq c \leq \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n$. This $c$ will be in the intersection.

Show directly that $c \in \bigcap \limits_{n \geq 1} (a_n, b_n)$ by showing that for each $k$, $a_k < c < b_k$. You can do this by noting that $a_k < \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$ since the sequence is strictly increasing, and similarly for $b_k$.



Thank you a lot for this answer and the remarks !
